# Jackson deserialize date-time strings to long?

Tags: java, datetime, jackson

I have date-time strings in JSON like this:

```
"dateRange": {
  "before": "2021-07-15T23:00:00.000Z",
  "after": "2021-07-31T22:59:00.000Z"
}
```

I'm using Jackson, and in the process of writing my DTO:

```
class MyClass {

    private DateRange dateRange;

    class DateRange {
        private Long before;
        private Long after;
    }
}
```

I am wondering what is the best way to get Jackson to deserialize the above strings to milliseconds (Long)? e.g. if I was hand-coding it would be something like `Instant.parse(dateRange.before).toEpochMilli()`.

Note both `before` and `after` fields are optional in the JSON, either one can be absent, so thinking of modelling them as `Long` instead of `long` so I can check for null. E.g. these are all valid:

```
"dateRange": {}
```

```
"dateRange": {
  "before": "2021-07-15T23:00:00.000Z"
}
```

```
"dateRange": {
  "after": "2021-07-15T23:00:00.000Z"
}
```

```
// No dateRange prop is also allowed
```

I was having a look here: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-dates, but there's a lot of options, so I'm not sure which is best?

Update: This seems to work OK:

```
class MyClass {

    private DateRange dateRange;

    class DateRange {
        private Date before;
        private Date after;
    }
}
```

```
MyClass myClass = ...
myClass.getDateRange().getBefore().getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use either `@JsonFormat` or add date formatter to Object mapper. It all depends on your use case. Both are good options. If this is an isolated use case in you application where you need similar conversion, you could use `@JsonFormat`. But if it's a standard across your application, I would probably suggest to set the formatter on Objectmapper to avoid writing annotations on all the classes.